# Two modals after "There is....."?

Tags: grammar

A native English speaker is talking about poverty and difficulty in paying the bills.

**"There is going to have to come a point where they all line up at the same time."** [Poverty in UK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFTk6HigTXU) (See: 3:09-3:14)

The structure **"There is going to have to a point....."** caught my attention. I don't know if this structure is correct usage or just colloquial.

Secondly, based on her usage **"..going to..."**, I wonder, has she already had situation where all the bills came one after the other and she wasn't able to pay? Or is she simply predicting that there will be a time (in the future), where all the bills will come one after the other and she won't be able to pay them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the expression *There is going to have to come a point where…* is perfectly idiomatic.

Its use implies nothing about what the speaker has already experienced; it is only a prediction.